# Is it possible to not trigger ripple effect on scroll?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

**Actual Result**:
Ripple effect triggered on scroll ([Video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0jdp.gif))

**Expected Result**: Ripple effect is only triggered on click just like in Android Views

**Code**:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            MyApp {
                Content()
            }
        }
    }
}

@Preview
@Composable
fun Content() {
    val items = List(100) { "Item number $it" }
    LazyColumn {
        items(items = items) { item ->
            Text(
                text = item,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .clickable { }
                    .padding(16.dp)
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Related issue tracker:

1. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/182551482
2. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/168524931

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been fixed in Compose version 1.0.0-rc01

Comment: This `1.0.0-rc01` works, however, has some complications with compose @Preview. As an alternative, you can use compose version `1.0.0-beta09`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set options in your `Modifier.clickable` like that :

```kotlin
Modifier.clickable(
    interactionSource = MutableInteractionSource(),
    indication = null, 
    onClick = {
            /* Action */
    }
)
```